# Custom iOS SDK's approval from Apple

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am creating my own custom SDK. Cocoa touch framework I will be creating. I want to be sure that my code is as per the apple guideline's and it is not violating any rules of it. So like any iOS app goes under approval, I want my SDK also approved by apple. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple only reviews complete Apps.